# getting the positions of multiple images using javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want to achieve is when the user stops scrolling I want to position the closest image to the centre to the centre. This will, I think, involve me running a series of `if` statements to determine which image is closest to the centre. I will be able to do this but before that the offsets I am getting are wrong. I am struggling to get my head around getting the images positioning's I know it has something to do with offset but I need some guidance because the offset values are not right. Take a look at this link http://bit.ly/PDz2JD and look at the function `setupHscroll` within that look at `getImageOffset` I think this is where the problem lies.

```
function getImageOffset() {
   var arr = new Array;
   var images = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("img");
   for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
       arr.push(images[i].offsetLeft);
       console.log(images[i].offsetLeft - rect.left);
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Please help and if possible help me understand. Thanks and am I using the right thing to get the position of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#offset-attributes

offsetLeft will retrieve the offset relative to the offsetParent.

If you can, I would recommend bringing in jQuery for the `$.offset()` functionality.

Otherwise, try this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: Never mind had a dumb moment just needed to getBoundingClientRect and minus it and really jQuery!! why! But thanks.

Comment: why Jquery?? I can give you 100 reasons o.O

Answer (score 0):

In your simple case, you can do something like this: for every image (or better, every `<div>` that contains it), take its `offsetLeft` and add half of its `offsetWidth`. Then take the `offsetWidth` of `#container` and divide it by two, then subtract the amount of its `marginLeft` style property.

Find the image which has its value closest to this one and you're done with it.